# Spark DataFrame handling corrupted record

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

In spark dataFrame, how to handle corrupted record?. Actually, I am looking for the corrupted record should persist to another file for later review. Mode - `DROPMALFORMED` option will drop corrupted record from the dataset. it will help.

```
val data = sparkSession.read
                       .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
                       .json("file:///C:/finances.json")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to persist `corrupted` records then you can filter those out into another dataframe and write it to file.

The catch here is to use PERMISSIVE(default) and **not** DROPMALFORMED mode as it would drop the corrupted records you wish to capture.

> PERMISSIVE: tries to parse all lines: nulls are inserted for missing tokens and extra tokens are ignored.

Then, depending upon your clause of corruptness, you can filter the rows for `null` values.

Comment: with out mode option , it is giving corrupted column in DF. I need to process it  two times .. one for if not corrupted column and corrupted column

Comment: Can you please mention the definition of your `corruptness`, like what makes a record corrupt?